# ClassCastException: ActiveMQMapMessage cannot be cast to ActiveMQMapMessage

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a MessageListener reading messages from a DLQ that I have messages go to after a few retries to process them fails. I want to work with these messages on the DLQ in my app.

If I put a breakpoint inside the onMessage() method, the IDE shows that message received in the onMessage(Message) method is of type ActiveMQMapMessage, but any code disagrees; such as instanceof or casting.

I get this error in Wildfly logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage
```

I'm running a external ActiveMQ broker, and have Wildfly configured to work with that.
Code deployed to Wildfly puts a message on a queue.

Code running outside of Wildfly reads the message , tries to process it, but fails. The ActiveMQ configuration is set to retry x many times and then place that message on a DLQ.

The running broker, and all of the activeMQ code dependencies is/uses ActiveMQ 5.13.3

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1 : JDK Versions**

I have checked the JDK version on which everything's (Wildfly, ActiveMQ Broker, Queue processor program) running (1.8.0_111) and also anything that I compile:
pom.xml

`<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>`

**UPDATE 2 : Wildfly config**

Wildfly is running with standalone.xml to which I've added the messaging-activemq extension:

`<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>`

and subsystem (both copied as is from standalone-full.xml):

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

I've modified ra.xml inside activemq-rar-5.13.3.rar to disable the embedded broker, and deployed that file to standalone/deployments/

For it, I've added configuration, so that it can use the external broker:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="activemq-rar">
                <archive>
                    activemq-rar-5.13.3.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                    tcp://localhost:61616
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="UserName">
                    defaultUser
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="Password">
                    defaultPassword
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ActiveMQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQConnectionFactory"/>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="example.queue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="example.queue">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            example.queue
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

I've added a `<mdb>` section to have it use the deployed rar:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">            
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-rar"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
```

**UPDATE 3**
Full Stack

```
17:13:38,565 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession] (default-threads - 8) error dispatching message: : javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.mycompany.DLQReader$$$view74.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.mycompany.DLQReader$$$endpoint1.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.MessageEndpointProxy$MessageEndpointAlive.onMessage(MessageEndpointProxy.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.MessageEndpointProxy.onMessage(MessageEndpointProxy.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.run(ActiveMQSession.java:916)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ServerSessionImpl.run(ServerSessionImpl.java:169)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:223)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage
    at com.mycompany.DLQReader.onMessage(DLQReader.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
   ... 55 more
```

Comment: Some common reasons for same-class ClassCastException errors are multiple class loaders and JDK version incompatibility. Can you post the full stacktrace?  Are there multiple activemq client jars present in the runtime?

Comment: @MattPavlovich _ Are there multiple activemq client jars present in the runtime?_ Could it be that the deployed resource adapter conflicts with the `messaging-activemq` subsystem? If I don't add that , I get `DLQReader.CREATE: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEJB0383: No message listener of type javax.jms.MessageListener found in resource adapter activemq-rar` during wildfly startup; an issue I could find no better solution to...

Answer (score 0):

Are you casting the message to ActiveMQMapMessage at com.mycompany.DLQReader.onMessage(DLQReader.java:67) ? You must have 2 paths to the activemq jars. What does your application contains in terms of jars ? Do you specify a jboss-deployment-structure.xml ?